# Custom Kivy kivy.properties.Property?

Tags: python, properties, kivy

## Question

How do I use custom types with kivy 2.1.0 while maintaining all of the automatic bindings? I want to use on_property events when mything.foo changes, while maintaining kv language bindings to mything.foo. There are two variations in this code with comments explaining how the outputs change. Tests were done by commenting one or the other out.

py file:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('2.1.0')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.event import EventDispatcher
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.logger import Logger


class MyType(EventDispatcher):
    foo = StringProperty("New")


class Consumer(BoxLayout):
    mything = ObjectProperty(MyType())

    def on_mything(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Logger.info(f"Consumer: Changed {self.mything=}")

    def click(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Assign Property:
        # on_mything executes: False
        # button text updates: True
        self.mything.foo = "Clicked"

        # Assign Object:
        # on_mything executes: True
        # button text updates: False
        # self.mything = MyType(foo="Clicked")


class AliasApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Consumer()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    AliasApp().run()
```

kv file:

```
#:kivy 2.1.0
<Consumer>:
    foo: "initialized in kv"
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Button:
        text: self.parent.mything.foo
        on_touch_down: self.parent.click()
```

Both of these are the documented, expected, behavior, but both break something. I assume there's a way to not break things.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

## My Ideal

I'd like to add something like this to MyType:

```
Property.custom_property(observe=['foo', 'bar'])
```

Then create a property in Consumer like this:

```
mything = CustomProperty()
```

## Possibilities I've Considered

### AliasProperty

I've read documentation and examples. They're all partial examples, but they all seem to suggest that you're creating a property in Consumer to use in Consumer, and I want a way to consume an external property.

### Manual Binding

I could implement an updated EventHandler in MyType and manually subscribe to an updated event. It seems like this would work as long as I only change the properties of mything and don't replace the whole object.

### Subclassing

I've tried but failed to find information about subclassing kivy.properties.Property. It seems like an internal thing, not not meant for mere mortals like me.

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) addressing your main problem.

Comment: @ApuCoder Thankyou for the help. Is this any better? I reworked it into an open problem instead of asking for help doing a specific thing.

Comment: In your method click when you're reassigning (or changing) object `MyType()` to `mything` (which happens to be an `ObjectProperty`) ONLY then `mything` changes, and thus `on_mything` triggers. If you also want the text (that has been bound to this property's some property) to be changed, change the definition of 'mything' as `mything = ObjectProperty(MyType(), rebind=True)`.

Comment: @ApuCoder Okay, that's workable. Thanks. If I'm understanding, I need to use an immutable type with an ObjectProperty set to rebind=true to both automatically bind changes to mything to execute on_mything, and make references in to mything.foo in the kv language follow the changes.